# Does the Quality of the Pictures Taken by a USB 3.0 Camera Depend on Cable Length?

Tags: digital-communications, snr, camera, hardware

I've got a JAI GO-5000-USB camera and have tried several cable lengths, ranging from 40cm to 5m.

So far, I haven't observed many differences in the quality of the pictures I've taken. Since I want to avoid a later realization that the quality isn't that good after all, I'm hoping that someone with experience with USB 3.0 cameras and longer cable lengths could warn me in advance.

Now my question is:
Has anyone experienced a decreasing quality of taken pictures depending on longer cable lengths? When did the problems start and in which way did they appear? Is it possible to measure or visualize those effects?

I've tried to visualize them with histograms, but that didn't really show anything useful at all.

Comment: Maybe it depends how your camera works. If it dynamically choose quality based on wire transfer rate, it can gives you lower quality on long cable. If long cable generate more transfer errors, and it must be re-transmited, then your camera is seeing lower transfer rate, then changes to lower quality. But it is only my imagination. For example, if you have slower Internet connection, then youtube gives you worse quality, like 240p mode. But how that camera works? I dont know. Maybe look what compression this camera is using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the data in the USB cable is digital.
Namely there is either an error in the data or the data is the same at any place along the cable.

Comment: And if a transmission error occurs, it will be caught by checksums in the USB protocol and possibly also at higher levels.

Comment: You can find more about USB checksums here: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/whitepapers/crcdes.pdf. Also note that, even if the data is the same, a longer or defective cable may decrease USB's data rate.